# liquibase and spring boot integration test h2db Table "" not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, liquibase, h2db

[image: Integration Test Config]

[image: Liquibase Config]

[image: H2 Config]

Liquibase ran and created the tables as you can see on logs, but when Test executes the table can't be found.

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EXAM" not found; SQL statement:
select exam0_.id_exam as id_exam1_11_, exam0_.code as code2_11_, exam0_.created_at as created_3_11_, exam0_.name as name4_11_, exam0_.synonym as synonym5_11_, exam0_.type as type6_11_, exam0_.updated_at as updated_7_11_ from exam exam0_ where exam0_.id_exam not in  (select exam2_.id_exam from exam_restriction examrestri1_ inner join exam exam2_ on examrestri1_.id_exam=exam2_.id_exam where examrestri1_.id_laboratory=?) [42102-194]

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have this repo https://github.com/brunooliveiramac/snack-store/tree/master/monolitic-application/snacks  and its working properly there.